# program that reads in ten numbers and displays the number of distinct numbers and the distinct numbers separated by one space

Tags: java, eclipse

I know that this question has been asked before, but not in the the format that I'm writing my code.. Just started taking java classes so I am not familiar with any complex java.. the code below consists of basically all the java I know. Please help! Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class problem2try {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declarations 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);  
        int [] inputList = new int [10]; 
        int [] distinctArray = new int [10]; 
        int num; 
        int counter = 0; 

        //input 
        System.out.print("Please enter in 10 integers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++)
        {
            num = keyboard.nextInt(); 
            inputList[i] = num; 
        }

        //processing
        distinctArray[0] = inputList[0]; 
        for (int i = 1; i < inputList.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputList.length; j++)
            {
                if (inputList[i] == inputList[j])
                {
                    counter++; 
                    continue; 
                }
                else
                {
                    distinctArray[i] = inputList[i];
                }
            }
        }

        //output
        System.out.println("The number of distinct numbers is " + counter);
        System.out.print("The distict numbers are: ");
        for (int x=0; x<distinctArray.length; x++)
        {
            if (distinctArray[x] != 0)

                System.out.print(distinctArray[x] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use a Set<Integer>

Comment: I just started learning java so I am not familiar with HashMap... Is there any way to solve it simply the way I'm diong it?

Comment: sometimes it is best to plot out your logic on paper first, and before long (maybe years) it will become second nature, see @dana answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic in the "processing" block seemed off.  I modified it to check the current number (outer loop) to all of the known numbers (inner loop).  If no match was found, it is appended to the list of known numbers and the count is incremented.

I also modified the "output" code to print the first `counter` numbers from the list of known numbers.  Values past that index are uninitialized.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class problem2try {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declarations 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);  
        int [] inputList = new int [10]; 
        int [] distinctArray = new int [10]; 
        int num; 
        int counter = 0; 

        //input 
        System.out.print("Please enter in 10 integers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++)
        {
            num = keyboard.nextInt(); 
            inputList[i] = num; 
        }

        //processing
        for (int i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++)
        {
            boolean found = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
            {
                if (inputList[i] == distinctArray[j])
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                distinctArray[counter++] = inputList[i];
            }
        }

        //output
        System.out.println("The number of distinct numbers is " + counter);
        System.out.print("The distict numbers are: ");
        for (int x=0; x<counter; x++)
        {
            System.out.print(distinctArray[x] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```